# Submit form from javascript with form url

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a button. And I have a form that calls celery task. form has url, smth like

```
http://example.com/export/?user=user123&timedelta=10
```

I need to submit this form from confirm dialog.
How it should work... In user profile admin presses a button, javascript confirmation appears, admin clicks ok and the form from this url should be submitted. I'm sooo new to javascript and frontend programming. I need your help.

Comment: I'd read: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ and have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: @CharliePrynn I wouldn't look at *anything* on w3schools, since they have a habit of putting up information that is flat out wrong. Go for something that's actually reliable, such as the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Fair enough. Can't say I've used it in great detail myself so I have not noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    var r=confirm("Press a button");
        if (r==true)
          {

//Form is on another page so
window.location="your_url_withquerystring"
          }
        else
          {

          }
```

Comment: hm... that is similar to what I need))))

Answer (score 1):

use jquery submit()

```
$('#yourFormID').submit();
```

Comment: Something people usually forget when using this: Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.

Comment: but... how to make a call to a form that is not on this page?

Comment: not on this page... u mean your foem is somewhere and conformation is somwwhere.. not getting you

Comment: I have a page with a button... and have another page that should be submitted... literally, I should submit a form from another form via url))) a bit complicated))